# How to autopopulate fields on Pydantic model in Pydantic V2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Say I have a model like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    url: str
    id: str
```

I'd like to autofill the `id` field using data from the url.

```py
url = 'https://www.example.com/open-requests/myid123'

instance = MyModel(url=url)
print(instance.id)  # 'myid123'
```

If I was using dataclasses, normally I'd just be able to overwrite the `__post_init__` method and could do some extra stuff there. (**Note**: This method is still not optimal)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyModel:
    url: str
    id: str = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.id = self.url.split('/')[-1]
```

I'd like to **not** have to assign the `id` fields type to `str | None = None`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

## How to autofill Pydantic V2 model fields

As I write this, I found 2 ways of doing it, I'll show what I think is the more readable one first, though none of them seem to be official.

### Method 1: `model_validator` decorator from V2

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    url: str
    id: str

    @model_validator(mode='before')
    def autofill_id(cls, data):
        if 'id' not in data:
            data['id'] = data['url'].split('/')[-1]
        return data
```

In my opinion this method is more readable and specific because you can write more than 1 AND name them explicitly, which is better for autopopulating multiple field.

### Method 2: Overwriting the `__init__` method

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    url: str
    id: str

    def __init__(self, **data):
        if 'id' not in data:
            data['id'] = data['url'].split('/')[-1]
        super().__init__(**data)
```

Again, not as pretty, but it does get the job done.

Both will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want to allow an empty string `""` to ever end up as the value of the `id` field, you could use that as a default.

Then you can define a regular [`field_validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#field-validators) for the `id` field that looks at the [`FieldValidationInfo`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/pydantic_core_schema/#pydantic_core.core_schema.FieldValidationInfo) object. The latter will contain the data for the *previously validated* fields in its `data` property.

**Note**: The order of field definition is important! Fields are still validated in the order they were defined. So if you define `url` *after* `id`, this will not work because the `url` value will not be present in the validation info object.

Lastly, you would have to [configure](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict) the `validate_default` setting on the model to be `True`.

It would look something like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator
from pydantic_core.core_schema import FieldValidationInfo


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = {"validate_default": True}

    url: str
    id: str = ""

    @field_validator("id", mode="before")
    def default_from_url(cls, v: object, info: FieldValidationInfo) -> object:
        if v != "":
            return v
        return info.data["url"].split("/")[-1]


instance = MyModel(url="https://www.example.com/open-requests/myid123")
print(instance.id)  # myid123
```

Obviously, this means that even if you *explicitly* pass an empty string during initialization, the `id` validator will still do its thing and take the value from the `url` field, which is why the first assumption is crucial here.

The benefit of this approach over the [`model_validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#model-validators) IMO is that you deliberately encapsulate the logic for that one specific field (`id`) in that one validation method. Of course if you want to populate *more than one* field based on other model fields, the `model_validator` approach makes much more sense.

Another minor benefit of having *some* default value is that you will not receive complaints from type checkers or your IDE, if you *omit* a value for `id` during initialization.

---

**PS**:

If literally *any* string should be acceptable, you could still use `None` as a default without changing the field type, as long as your field validator works in `before`-mode. (That last part is not important for the previous solution with the `""` default, but it is crucial for this one.)

The only downside is that the default assignment will be rightfully considered a type error by static type checkers like Mypy, so you would have to deliberately ignore it.

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = {"validate_default": True}

    url: str
    id: str = None  # type: ignore[assignment]

    @field_validator("id", mode="before")
    def default_from_url(cls, v: object, info: FieldValidationInfo) -> object:
        if v is not None:
            return v
        return info.data["url"].split("/")[-1]
```

Same result.